# TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: python, string

I have a bit of a problem at the moment, I'm quite new to python and to people who code a lot this might seem really easy to answer. We've been tasked to do a '99 bottles of beer on the wall' challenge and I wanted to make mine slightly better by asking the user what they'd like in the bottle. However I keep getting an `error: TypeError: must be str, not builtin_function_or_method`

```
input("What would you like inside your bottle?")

def sing(b, end):
    print(b or 'No more', 'bottle'+('s' if b-1 else ''), end)

for i in range(99, 0, -1):
    sing(i, 'of'+input+'on the wall,')
    sing(i, 'of'+input+',')
    print('Take one down, pass it around,')
    sing(i-1, 'of'+input+'on the wall.\n')
```

any help would be much appreciated, thanks :3

Comment: Please provide us with code samples in text so we can cut and paste. That way we can help you more effectively. but look at your print statement in sing. you combine if statements and or and stuff inside the print. Should not do that

Comment: Post the code here, not a link to it. If the code is too long, reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Paste code instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

`input()` method returns value to be assigned to a variable. [Compare with the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). Now you are referencing a method not a variable.

You need something like

```
something = input('Say sth. ')
print(something)
```

Answer (score 2):

`input` is a builtin function, so when you do `'of'+input+'on the wall'`, you just try to concatenate a function to a string, which doesn't make a lot of sense ;)
(the interpreter is explicitly telling you that)

`input` returns a string you doesn't assign to a variable, so try `user_input = input("What would you like inside the bootle?")` and then using `user_input` instead of `input` in your code.